# Overloaded non-member operator== undefined?

Tags: c++, operator-overloading

g++ 4.5.3 (cygwin)

I am having trouble in defining the overloaded non-member operator==. The compiler outputs the error message

> main.cpp:11: undefined reference to `slip::operator==(bool, slip::SlipDatum const&)

and I can't figure out what I'm doing wrong. It seems to me that all of the definitions are visible and all the function prototypes and code are correct. When the overload is used as a member function, as in "(SlipDatum&)Y == (bool)X", there are no problems. As a non-member function I keep getting an undefined reference.

Another issue is that when '#include SlipOp.h"' is removed from Slip.cpp then SlipDatum is undefined in Slip.cpp. I've looked at SlipDatum.h and SlipOp.h is not needed. I've looked at SlipDatum.cpp and SlipOp.h is needed and included. SlipOp.h is not needed or referenced in Slip.cpp, so why does the compiler think that it's needed?

The sample code used follows:

main.cpp

```
# include <cstdlib>
# include "Slip.h"
# include <iostream>
using namespace std;
using namespace slip;

int main(int argc, char** argv) {
   SlipDatum Y;
   bool X = true;
   if (X == Y) cout << "here" << endl;
   return 0;
}
```

Slip.h

```
#ifndef SLIP_H
#define SLIP_H
# include "SlipDatum.h"

namespace slip {
   bool      operator==(const bool   X, const SlipDatum& Y);  // Y == X
}; // namespace slip
#endif  /* SLIP_H */
```

Slip.cpp

```
# include "Slip.h"
# include "SlipCellBase.h"
# include "SlipOP.h"
# include "SlipDatum.h"

inline  bool operator==(const bool X, const SlipDatum& Y) 
     { return const_cast<SlipDatum&>(Y) == X; };
```

SlipDef.h

```
#ifndef SLIPDEF_H
#define SLIPDEF_H

# include <string>

using namespace std;

namespace slip {

#ifdef UCHAR
   # undef UCHAR
#endif
#ifdef ULONG
   # undef ULONG
#endif
#ifdef DOUBLE
   # undef DOUBLE
#endif
#ifdef PTR
   # undef PTR
#endif

   typedef unsigned char   UCHAR;               //  8-bits
   typedef unsigned long   ULONG;               // 32-bits
   typedef double          DOUBLE;              // 64-bits
   typedef void *          PTR;                 // pointer
   typedef string *        STRING;              // C String

   union Data {                                 // Slip data contents
       bool      Bool;                          // compiler defined
       char      Chr;                           //  8-bits
       UCHAR     UChr;                          //  8-bits
       long      Long;                          // 32-bits
       ULONG     ULong;                         // 32-bits
       double    Double;                        // 64-bits
       PTR       Ptr;                           // 
       STRING    String;                        // pointer to a string
   }; // union Data
} // namespace slip
#endif  /* SLIPDEF_H */
```

SlipCellBase.h

```
#ifndef _SLIPCELLBASE_H
#define _SLIPCELLBASE_H

# include "SlipDef.h"

using namespace std;

namespace slip {
  class SlipCellBase {
     friend class SlipOp;
  private:
      void*         operation;   //! Operations cell can perform
      SlipCellBase* leftLink;    //! Pointer to preceding cell
      SlipCellBase* rightLink;   //! Pointer to following cell
      Data          datum;       //! SLIP cell data field
 protected:
      void** getOperator() const 
           { return &const_cast<SlipCellBase*>(this)->operation; }
      static void** getOperator(SlipCellBase* X) 
           { return   &(X->operation);   }
  }; // class SlipCellBase
}; // namespace slip
#endif  /* SLILPCELLBASE_H */
```

SlipDatum.h

```
#ifndef SLIP_DATUM_H
#define SLIP_DATUM_H
# include "SlipCellBase.h"
namespace slip {
  class SlipDatum : public SlipCellBase {
  public:
     bool       operator==(const bool X);  // Y == X
  }; // SlipDatum
}; // namespace slip
#endif
```

SlipDatum.cpp

```
# include "SlipDatum.h"
# include "SlipOP.h"
# include "SlipCellBase.h"

bool SlipDatum::operator==(const bool X)
    { return ((SlipOp*)*getOperator())->equal(*this, X); }
```

SlipOp.h

```
#ifndef _SLIPOP_H
#define _SLIPOP_H
# include "SlipDatum.h"

using namespace slip;

namespace slip {
  class SlipOp {
  public:
     virtual bool equal(SlipDatum& Y, const bool X)  = 0;
  }; // class SlipOp
}; // namespace slip
#endif  /* _SLIPOP_H */
```

SlipBool.h

```
#ifndef _SLIPboolOP_H
#define _SLIPboolOP_H
# include "SlipOp.h"

namespace slip {
  class SlipBoolOp : public SlipOp {
  public:
     virtual bool equal(SlipDatum& Y, const bool   X);
  }; // class SlipBoolOp
}; // namespace slip
#endif  /* SLIPboolOP_H */
```

SlipBool.cpp

```
# include "SlipBoolOp.h"
# include "SlipDatum.h"

using namespace slip;

namespace slip {
  bool SlipBoolOp::equal (SlipDatum& Y, const bool X) {
    return false;
  }; // bool SlipBoolOp::equal (SlipDatum& Y, const SlipDatum& X) 

}; // namespace slip
```

Comment: tl;dr but you almost certainly want to remove `inline` from the definition of `operator==` in `Slip.cpp`. There may be other issues other than this. Oh yes, and you probably want to put the definition in the `slip` namespace if you meant to define the same function that you declare in the header file.

Answer (score 3):

in slip.cpp you define the operator== in global scope, i.e. you missed the namespace:

```
namespace slip {
  bool operator==(bool X, const SlipDatum& Y) 
  { return const_cast<SlipDatum&>(Y) == X; };
}
```

PS: the const_cast should not be necessary, since `operator==(SlipDatum&, bool)` should take the SlipDatum by const reference as well. i.e. in slipdatum.h/cpp:

```
namespace slip {
  class SlipDatum : public SlipCellBase {
  public:
     bool       operator==(bool X) const; // <--! *this is left constant                                          
  }; 
};
```

Comment: +1, alternatively, in the global namespace: `bool slip::operator==(bool X, const slip::SlipDatum& Y) ...`. The `const` in the first argument is misleading (it will be dropped from the declaration). Defining the function outside the namespace but with the qualification has the advantage that it inhibits *self-declaration* (i.e. if you mistake the namespace the compiler will yell, rather than the linker).

Comment: I made changes (below) and the error message now shows that the reference from main is undefined (undefined reference to `slip::operator==(bool, slip::SlipDatum const&)). The changes made were to add namespace and remove const_cast in slip.cpp, change prototype in SlipDatum.h to const, add const SlipDatum& to prototype in SlipOP.h (required to remove errors), add namespace to SlipDatum.cpp. When I added slip::operator==(X,Y) - to conform to error message - the returning error is slip::operator==(bool, SlipDatum&) is undefined. Different error, same frustration.

Comment: The error suggests it is looking for `slip::operator==(bool, SlipDatum&)`, i.e. the second param is not const. That means, you either have not made that parameter const in the header, or you have not recompiled all sources that include that header, so some older object files still refer to the non-const version.

Comment: Cross my heart I have! Just check Slip.*. First argument non-const. Second argument const. However, when I removed 'inline' from Slip.cpp it compiled correctly. Now the interesting thing is that I have had continuous problems with using 'inline'. Sometimes the compiler accepts it, at others I get (just as here) and undefined reference. Placement of 'inline' in the header or source file seems to have the same effect. The code shown in Slip.* is actual code. It would be nice to have a 1-line method be inlined. The separation of code into .h and .cpp is qualitative.  Drat, a compiler bit me.

Comment: Forget about inline - in most cases. It's in most cases only a hint for the compiler. On the one hand it can ignore it, on the other hand it can inline functions that you did not declare inline, just as it sees fit. Modern compilers even can do link time optimization, inlining those one-liners across translation unit boundaries. The one and only use case for inline today is when you *define* nontemplate functions in header files, but outside class definitions. Then you need inline to avoid ODR violations.

Comment: Thanks @ArneMertz. Even so it seems that 'inline' should not cause a method / function to be undefined. I have used inline in class methods and have had 'undefined function' reported. I think for me the rule is "don't inline, not never". Thank you. Your initial answer that I was missing a namespace in Slip.cpp was correct. And may today be the best day of your life and every succeeding day better. art

Comment: @ArthurSchwarez: Marking a function as inline means that you _have_ to provide a definition for it in every translation unit where it is used. If you only provide a definition in one translation unit it may well cause the function to be undefined at link time, although technically anything could happen as the behaviour is undefined if you don't follow the rules.